# PowerShell keeps throwing an exception

Tags: exception, powershell, error-handling, active-directory

```
$RootPath = "W:\"
$OutFile = "I:\Permissions.csv"
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
#Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs)
    {

        $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($ACL.IdentityReference.Value) 
        #$objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) 
        $objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        $objUser.Value

        $DName = ([adsi]"LDAP://<SID=$($ACL.IdentityReference.value)>").distinguishedName

        $s = $DName
        $s -replace "(CN=)(.*?),.*",'$2'

        $dname.split("=")[1].split(",")[0]

        #Show User
        Write-Host “`r`nThe user mapped to SID $($objSID) is $($objUser.value)`r`n” -f “Red”

        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $dname.split("=")[1].split(",")[0]  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }
}
```

I get the following error messages.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At I:\PermissionExporter.ps1:31 char:57
+         $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $dname.split <<<< ("=")[1].split(",")[0]  + "," 
+ $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.P
ropagationFlags
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (split:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Does anyone have any idea whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

$DNName isn't doing what you expect.  Add a breakpoint and verify that this:

$dname.split("=")[1].split(",")[0]

is working correctly.

Comment: Its actually not liking the SPLIT method. Any workaround or means of getting the CN value?

Comment: Which split?  It said can't call a method on a null expressions.  That means at some point your variable doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: The distinguishedName property isn't a string, but a property of type System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.  I'm wondering if that's causing any issues...

Comment: Any recommended fix? I mouse over the dname and I see CN=ABC,DN=company,DN=ABC...

Comment: Changing the line to read: `$DName = ([adsi]"LDAP://<SID=$($ACL.IdentityReference.value)>")[0].distinguishedName.ToString()` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to do pipe the parent object through `get-member` just to see if you are getting the object you *think* you're getting (can't count how many times I've been bitten by that).